# need to write a new random generator in R

Tags: r, random

I need to generate 7 random numbers between -1,1 which sum of them equals to 1. I used this code to do so.

```
 diff(c(0, sort(round(runif(7,-1,1),2)), 1))
```

But I have a big problem with this.

one output of this code is **-0.89,  0.21,  0.00,  0.21,  0.30,  0.19,  0.61, -0.63**.

The problem is it is uniform I guess so it every time generates big random numbers in the first and last number which is not I want. I need it to be spread to all numbers. 
ex. **0.22 -.21 .33 -.12 0.11 0.35 -0.08** (the sum is not equal to 1 just an example)

Do you know who I can write a code to get this kind of random numbers?

Comment: FYI: if you need 7 random numbers that always sum to 1, then you get 6 random numbers and 1 dependent number. Is this true?

Comment: You say that it's a problem having big random numbers in the first and last ... when you `sort`, your lowest (most-negative) is furthest from 0, so when you do `diff(c(0,sort(...),1))`, your first is always a relatively large difference. Perhaps you mean `diff(c(-1,...,1))`?

Comment: @r2evans yeah I see it is the problem but if I take it how I can get sum = 1

Comment: @user2428538 i would be thankful, if you accept my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 solutions, and both of them work with infinite loop:

**Solution 1:**

You can consider 6 randoms, and 1 dependant so the sum of them can be 1. But, it might happen that, an element become more than 1 or less than -1. Therefore, we cannot accept all the answers.

```
while(T){
  res<-runif(6,-1,1)

  res<-append(res,1-sum(res))

  if(sum(res>1)==0)
    break
}

res
```

Output is:

```
-0.34038038  0.15811401 -0.20748670  0.26443104  0.45216639 -0.09912685  0.77228248
```

---

**Solution 2:**

we should continuesly generate different results, and hope to get a proper answer. But, inorder to reduce the time we must **round the randoms by 1 digit**:

```
while(T){
  res<-round(runif(7,-1,1), digits = 1)
  print(sum(res))
  if(sum(res)==1)

     break

  }

res
```

Output:

```
> res
[1] -0.6  0.2  0.4  0.7 -0.2  0.6 -0.1
```

Comment: I just tried it but it takes a lot of time and doesnot work

Comment: in your code the problem I guess is the sum(res) could be greater than 1

Comment: @user2428538 my second solution is now working as well.

Comment: but now the problem is one of the numbers less than -1. I need to have 7 number less than 1 and greater than -1

Comment: @user2428538 first one is also fixed, but the idea is somehow close to *second solution*

Comment: You should also check that the dependent value is not smaller than `-1`. After all the sum of the independent values might be as large as `6`.

Answer (score 5):

Your general idea is probably inspired by the answers linked in the [random](/questions/tagged/random) description. The standard problem is how to generate 7 numbers between 0 and 1 that add to 1. The answer is:

```
diff(c(0, sort(runif(6, 0, 1)), 1))
#> [1] 0.27960792 0.02035231 0.02638626 0.09945877 0.25134002 0.03379598 0.28905874
```

The necessary modifications for getting numbers between -1 and 1 are quite simple; just leave out the `sort`:

```
diff(c(0, runif(6, 0, 1), 1))
#> [1]  0.9961661 -0.6528227  0.5298829 -0.2087127 -0.2298045  0.2017705  0.3635203
```

How does this work? We again partition the space between zero and one. But b leaving out the sort, we allow for the possibility of going backward, i.e. negative numbers are possible. Here is the histogram for 1000 generations:

[image]

One weakness in this approach is that the first and last numbers are necessarily positive. If this bothers you, you can add an additional `sample`, e.g.:

```
sample(diff(c(0, runif(6, 0, 1), 1)), 7)
#> [1] -0.004242793 -0.725348335  0.385971491  0.320525822  0.389915347
#> [6]  0.053195271  0.579983197
```

Comment: By far the better answer, both mathematically rigorous and more performant, not requiring iterations.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but the problem is the random numbers should be all positive. So, I need 7 random number bet 0,1 which the sum = 1 and all the numbers are >0 and also, i need another 7 random numbers bet -1,1 in which the sum = 0 in the second case numbers could be positive or negetive

Comment: @user2428538 Well, I answered the first variation in passing with the first line of code. For the second variant just replace the final `1` with `0` in the last line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution like Salman Lashkarara. You should round the numbers to find a solution.

```
library(magrittr)

set.seed(42)
x <- 1

while(sum(x) != 0){
  x <- runif(7,-1,1) %>%
    round(3)
}

x
#> [1]  0.155  0.559 -0.335 -0.230 -0.490 -0.557  0.898
sum(x)
#> [1] 0

Created on 2018-09-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).
```